# Rails: Is there a way to detect if an Active Record object was created with #dup?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a need in my app to have validations that apply only to records that are not the result of a dup.

Is there a way to detect if an object was duplicated via #dup or another way to apply a validation only to a record that was not a dup?

Comment: Do you have an example?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any straightforward solution but to add a `duplicated` boolean column for your model.

Create migration for your model:

```
$ rails g migration addDuplicatedColumnToModels
```

Update the migration file that just have been created: The following add the `duplicated` boolean column with a default: false

```
def change
  add_column :table_name, :duplicated, :boolean, default: false
end
```

Then when you duplicate a record:

```
@new_record = @record.dup
@new_record.duplicated = true
@new_record.save
```

Then you can use that field to filter your records

Answer (score 0):

Just tested `.dup` on an ActiveRecord object and saw that it sets the `id` to `nil`, it's like a new record.

```
u1 = User.last
u2 = u1.dup
p u1 == u2 # false
p u2.id # nil
p u2.new_record? # true
```

So without having much context, checking if the `id` is `nil` should do the trick.

Another way to do it is with `attr_accessor :dupped`

```
u1 = User.last
u2 = u1.dup
u2.dupped = true
```

Comment: That doesn't really tell you whether it was `dup`ed to begin with though, `id` is `nil` for every new record

Comment: I know and it's explained in the answer.  But without a context .. Alternatively a virtual attribute could be added and set to true after dup.